# WPF Autocompletebox inside Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, autocompletebox

I have a Datagrid with 5 Columns and I want to use an Autocompletebox inside this Datagrid. So far this is what I have.

```
class Products
{
    public string OxProd { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("OxProd: {0}", OxProd);
    }
}

class ListOfProducts
{
    public string LstProd {get; set;}
}

MainWindow()

List<Products> xProd = new List<Products>();

//Sql Connection to get the items

...

  while (rdr.Read())
    {
     xProd.Add(new Products() { OxProd = rdr.GetString(0) });
    }

 var DataListProd = new List<ListOfProducts>();

 DataListProd.Add(new ListOfProducts { LstProd = xProd.ToString()  });

//Until here everything is fine, xProd got all the items

 RelProdWindow.DataGrid1.ItemsSource = DataListProd;     
 RelProdWindow.Show();
```

The problem is with my XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <controls:AutoCompleteBox Name="Autbox_product" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" BorderBrush="Transparent"
             ???
             ???/>                                                                                                       
         </StackPanel>                                               
       </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I don't know how to bind the autocompletebox. I tried a lot of things but none of them worked. How can I bind to the autocompletebox inside a Datagrid?

EDIT:

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: what you actually want?? bind auto complete box with what ?? and what to do??

Comment: I want to bind autocompletebox with xProd. So when I load the Datagrid I can search the products in the autocompletebox inside the Datagrid. I tried some approaches but using the code above it did not bind.

Comment: try to put it inside CellEditingTemplate not CellTemplate